# Docker does not persists the NodeJS app's volume mounted data

Tags: docker, persist, volumes

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I already reviewed another similar post in StackOverflow but I cannot see where is the problem.

This is my docker-compose file:

```
  ## APP
  nodeServer:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./config/node-express/Dockerfile
    image: node-mysql-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 8745:8745
    volumes:
      - .:/home/dockeruser/src
      # - node_modules:/home/dockeruser/src/node_modules

    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
      
    restart: unless-stopped

 volumes: 
   node_modules:
```

And my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.4-alpine3.11

RUN apk add --no-cache python g++ make
ENV NODE_ENV=development
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "npm-shrinkwrap.json*", "./"]
RUN npm install --production 
RUN apk update && apk add bash


RUN addgroup -g 1010 -S docker && \
     adduser -u 1010 -S dockuser -G docker

USER dockuser
COPY . /home/dockuser/src
WORKDIR /home/dockuser/src

EXPOSE 3000 8745
CMD ["/bin/sh", "entrypoint.sh"]
```

I run the docker-compose.yml file in the app root, which means where I have all the app code. The docker file is in this path:

```
dockerfile: ./config/node-express/Dockerfile
```

After running this the app is working fine in the 3000 port and I can execute the container and see the code, but if I change something in the host the container is not updated. I also cannot see the node_modules created when I run the Dockerfile:

```
"docker-compose build --no-cache"

"docker-compose up"
```

First to do that I always delete the containers and the volumes just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue doing these changes.

**Dockefile:**

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
 volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
```

I am not sure the reason, but it works.